# Ruby Ternary Operator does not seem to be working on a hash assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the process of learning ruby (I have a java background).

I have assignment statements where the value of one `hash[:name_field]` is being assigned to another. But the value coming from the hash on the right was sometimes blank. This was crashing my code hence i added the ternary logic with `.nil ?` etc....

I am surprised though that this doesn't work... The error is :

```
undefined method `nil' for 1133:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

Below is the code:

```
people_traffic.each do |person|

  person_record = DaysTraffic.new 

  person_record[:name] = person[:name_filed].nil ? 0 : person[:name_filed]
  person_record[:age]  = person[:age_field].nil ? 0 :  person[:age_field]

  person_record.save
end
```

Why am I getting the `(NoMethodError)` for the `nil?`

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be `.nil?` (with a question mark) not `.nil`.  So in your case, that would be:

```
person_record[:name] = person[:name_filed].nil? ? 0 : person[:name_filed]
```

You can actually write this much simpler like so:

```
person_record[:name] = person[:name_filed] || 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `#to_i` turns `nil` into `0,` a good way to write something like this is:

```
person_record[:age] = person[:age_field].to_i
```